# Need help to code about precedence in Expression

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a compiler in c# for c++ language, which will compile and execute c++ code

But problem occurs when i try to assign an expression to a variable
example

```
int a= 1+2*3;
```

I don't know how can i precedent it.

CFG i am trying to use

```
E -> E+T | T
T -> T*F | F
F -> number | id | (E)
```

Comment: http://scheme2006.cs.uchicago.edu/11-ghuloum.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this I would recomment to use antlr. You can find a parser and lexer for cpp14 [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/cpp/CPP14Parser.g4). With these files you can generate c# code parsing and lexing cpp syntax.

Good luck!